# Angular 6 watch data changes from 3rd service

Tags: angular, typescript

Must be something very basic, but i got stuck with it.

In brief - i have 3 services: service0, service1, service3. Service1 store the data and service 2 & 3 work with it.

I want to subscribe to changes from the data attribute of the service1 from both services. How do i do it?

example:

```
export class Service0 implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(private service1: Service1) { }
  add(data): boolean { this.service1.addData(data); }
}

export class Service1 implements OnDestroy {
  data: Data;
  constructor() { }
  get data() { return this.data }

  addData(data) {
     if (this.servers.findIndex(el => el.hostname === s.hostname) === -1){    
        this.data.push(s);
     }
  }
}

export class Service2 implements OnDestroy {
  data: Data;
  constructor(private service1: Service1) { this.data = this.service1.data; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
i tried this, which is supposed to work(data service):

```
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

export class Service1 {
  data: Data[];

  constructor() { }
  get data() { return this.data }

  addData(data) {
     if (this.servers.findIndex(el => el.hostname === s.hostname) === -1){    
        this.data.push(s);
     }
  }

  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
     return of(this.data)
  }
}

export class Service2 implements OnDestroy {
 data: Data[];
 constructor(private service1: Service1) { 
    this.service1.getData().subscribe(data=>{
       this.data = data
       console.log(this.data)
    })  
 }
}
```

it was firing once the object is added, but in this case `console.log(this.data)` was showing an objects array only in the browser console, while `JSON.stringify(this.data)` and trying to call the properties - showing that an object is empty. 
Still prefer this solution, but can't figure out why is that happening?

Meanwhile for now i use `dataChanges = new Subject();` to emit an event once the data was changed in `Service1` and then

```
this.servers1.serversChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.data = this.service1.getData();
});
```

to fetch it. In this case its working.

Comment: You can have setter which will set data and additionally set up a `Subject` which will inform rest of the services that data was updated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to Subscribe to something, that something needs to be an Observable. For that we use libraries such us Rxjs. There are many rxjs Observables such us Subjects, BehaviorSubjects, AsyncSubjects etc. You can read more here [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/)

The bellow example shows how you can implement a simple Observable Data Service!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

Injectable()
export class Service0  {
    data: BehaviorSubject<string[]>;
    constructor() {
        this.data = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);
    }
    getData() {
        // Logic to get data from an http call
        // On Successful response
        this.data.next(responseData);
    }
}
```

Now after that you can Inject that service on any other Service, Component etc and subscribe to the data with ease.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Service0 } from '../service0.ts';

Injectable()
export class Service1  {
    data: string[];
    constructor(private service0: Service0) {
        service0.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        });
    }
    dataFunction() {
        // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

Now you second Service will always have the latest data that will be provided from the Service0.

I would also like to point out that if you use that in a Component, the best practice to actually do that without having any data leaks is to also unsubscribe from the Observable. Like that:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Service0 } from '../service0.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
  })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
    data: string[];
    dataSubscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private service0: Service0) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSubscription = this.service0.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.dataSubscription && this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

You won't need to do that inside a Singleton Service since you subscribe inside the constructor and that subscription will only last for the duration of that Service's lifespan. That constructor will only be called once. If that service isn'e a singleton, then you will have to implement the same logic because you will propably have to create multiple instances of that Service. Read about Singletons here [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).
I hope i gave you an answer to help you out with your work. Feel free to contact me about any questions.

Cheers

Comment: I like your solution with `BehaviorSubject` because those services which are getting data can be late with subscribe so +. I have only to ask about statement that **onDestroy** can't be implemented in service because documentation states "Lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe or service is destroyed."

Comment: You are actually correct. I have never used that before though because those services are usually getting destroyed when the app is destroyed. I will correct it. Thanks a lot and apologies for that .

Comment: hi i think there might be a bit of misunderstanding. data is imported into `Service1` (in my example) line by line from elsewhere (`Service0` which is actually gets the data.).

Comment: Well my response is a generic one. By making your data Observable you can import them wherever you want and have all the Services, components etc Updated with the latest data input. If that isn't the case then i might have misunderstood the issue.

Comment: Ok i saw your update. When you are calling the getData() function and then subscribing to it , you will get the current data that are pushed at that time . Meaning that if you call addData(newData) and don't call getData() again you will still get the previous version of the data without the newData. That's why i am recommending the subject() solution. Also an other thing. After calling the getData(), the observable (of) is getting created inside the scope of this function and then is destroyed. That way your subscription is actually one-off.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I put some idea in comments but here is code:

```
export class Service0 implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(private service1: Service1) {
        // In case when you only inform without passing data
        this.service1.dataChanges.subscribe(() => {
            // This service doesn't have 'data' member so do something else
        });

        // With passed data
        this.service1.dataChanges.subscribe((data) => {
            // This service doesn't have 'data' member so do something else
        });
    }

    add(data): boolean {
        this.service1.addData(data); // Could be changed now to use that setter
    }
}

export class Service1 implements OnDestroy {
    _data: Data;
    dataChanges = new Subject();

    constructor() {
    }

    get data() {
        return this._data;
    }

    set data(value) {
        this._data = value;
        this.dataChanges.next(); // or even pass here new value
    }
}

export class Service2 implements OnDestroy {
    data: Data;

    constructor(private service1: Service1) {
        this.data = this.service1.data;

        // In case when you only inform without passing data
        this.service1.dataChanges.subscribe(() => {
            this.data = this.service1.data;
        });

        // With passed data
        this.service1.dataChanges.subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
        });
    }
}
```